# Apply VAT 7% on shipping and products

Tags: tax, vat

I'm a bit confused with displaying VAT on shopping cart. I've tied to set up a 7% VAT (on porducts and shipping) but my Grant total including tax is still equal to grand total excluding tax.

I've created a 7% VAT rule in Sales > Manage tax and zone rules
I've also tried to define the most appropriate setting in Configuration > Sales > Tax
... but no result.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout our knowledge base on setting up VAT tax in Magento ([link](http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#tax/configuration-eu.html)).

In general you need to:

1. `Create a tax rate ( 7% ; YOUR COUNTRY )`
2. `Create a tax rule ( linking #1 with product & customer tax classes )`
3. `Ensure your products have the product tax class that you're using in #2`
4. `Update tax configuration ( per linked docs ).`